# getValueAt() en javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Quiero capturar el contenido de una celda en especifico de mi tabla, en jtable lo hacia con:
miTabla.getValueAt(int fila,int columna);

De que manera puedo hacerlo en javaFX?

Mi codigo:

```
//Archivo controlador de la app.
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private TableView <Proceso> tablaInfo;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaId;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaNombre;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaQuantum;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaRecursos;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaEstado;
    @FXML private TableColumn columnaTiempo;  
    ObservableList<Proceso> lista;

    @FXML private void botonIniciarClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        for (int i = 1 ; i < 13 ; i++){
            int Q = (int)((Math.random()*29)+1);
            Proceso proceso = new Proceso();
            proceso.id.set(i);
            proceso.nombre.set("Proceso "+i);
            proceso.quantum.set(Q);
            proceso.recursos.set(1);         
            proceso.estado.set("Ejecutando");
            proceso.tiempo.set(1);
            lista.add(proceso);    
        }

    public void Procesar(int cont){
        int idProcesar = tablaInfo.getValueAt(cont,0);
        //Aqui surge el error, "cannot find symbol method getValueAt()"
    }

}



//-----------------------Clase Proceso----------------------
public class Proceso{
    public SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty nombre = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleIntegerProperty quantum = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public SimpleDoubleProperty recursos = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty estado = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleIntegerProperty tiempo = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id.get();
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre.get();
    }
    public Integer getQuantum() {
        return quantum.get();
    }
    public Double getRecursos() {
        return recursos.get();
    }
    public String getEstado() {
        return estado.get();
    }
    public Integer getTiempo() {
        return tiempo.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente en JavaFX cambia completamente la filosofia de las tablas, no se parece en nada un JTable con un TableView.

//para obtener el nombre por ejemplo, yo lo hago recorriento fila por fila de la tabla y despues coginedo el valor de la columna que deseo

```
for (int i = 0; i < tbView.getItems().size(); i++)
    System.out.println(tbView.getItems().get(i).getNombre().toString());
```

Tambien olvide que lo puedes hacer de esta forma, con un for anidado, uno para recorrer las filas y el otro para las columnas que estan visibles

```
for (int i = 0; i < tbView.getItems().size(); i++)                        
    for (TableColumn column : tbView.getVisibleLeafColumns())            
        System.out.println(column.getCellData(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu ejemplo, tendrías que modificar el método 'Procesar' de la
siguiente forma:

```
public void Procesar(int cont){
    Proceso proc = tablaInfo.getItems().get(cont);
    int idProcesar = proc.getId();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Cada fila de 'tablaInfo' es un objeto del tipo 'Proceso'. Primero obtienes el objeto ubicado en la fila 'cont' y luego obtienes el campo que te interesa, en este caso el campo 'id', utilizando el método (propiedad) getId() definido en la clase (Proceso).

Comment: Ya lo solucione, gracias :)

Comment: @GaboReyes Si ya solucionaste tu pregunta publica tu solucion o si la respuesta de alguno te funciono marca la respuesta como aceptada.